# Find all psositive values of p such that $f(x) \in L^p(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = |\frac{1}{\ln(x)}|$. 
Find all positive values of p such that $f(x) \in L^p(0,1)$. 
A function is in $L^p$ if the integration is finite. but this is an inproper integral and i believe this is function does  not have an antiderivatives. is there a way for me to find all the values of p without computing the integral just using analysis thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have to determine for which $p\in\mathbb{R}^+$ the $p$-norm

$$||f||_p = \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|\ln(x)|^p}\mathrm{d}x \right)^{1/p} $$
is finite. With the substitution $t=-\ln(x)$
$$||f||_p^p= \int_0^{+\infty} t^{-p} e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t$$
This integral is convergent if and only if $p<1$ (check the convergence at $t=0$), in which case its value is given by the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

$$ ||f||_p = \Gamma(1-p)^{1/p}, \text{if  } p \in[0,1). $$

Answer (score 0):

Hints: 1. There is no problem at $0.$

2. $\ln x$ has a zero of order $1$ at $1.$

Comment: Yes i had come up with the conclusion that there is no problem at zero the case i am truly having problem with is at 1. i really need some help in that case

Comment: is there a way you can explain how to treat that case

Comment: Use $|\ln x| \approx |x-1|$ and see what happens.